# New project using Spring MVC 5 in eclipse, but I am having error 404

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and I am trying to make simple HelloWorld program i am following this tutorial https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/spring-mvc-5-hello-world-example.html

**AppConfig**

```
package main.java.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
"main.java"
})
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
}
```

**Dispatcher Servlet Initializer**

```
package main.java.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletDispatcherInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class <?> [] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class <?> [] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {
        AppConfig.class
    };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {
        "/"
    };
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
package main.java.controller;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import main.java.model.HelloWorld;

@Controller
public class JavaController {

@RequestMapping("/helloworld")
public String handler(Model model) {

    HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World Example Using Spring MVC 5!!!");
    helloWorld.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
    model.addAttribute("helloWorld", helloWorld);
    return "helloworld";
}
}
```

**Model**

```
package main.java.model;

public class HelloWorld {
private String message;
private String dateTime;
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}
}
```

**JSP**

```
...
      ${helloWorld.message}</h2>
      Server date time is : ${helloWorld.dateTime}
...
```

**File Path**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

i tried cleaning the server, close and open the browser, republish my project.

I don't know what to do now, please help me.

**my pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringMVC5</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC5</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>springmvc5-helloworld-exmaple Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

  <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: How are you calling your url?  Assuming that `SpringMVC5` is actually deployed to below webapps then `http:<webserver:port>/SpringMVC5/helloworld` should be correct

Comment: @ScaryWombat still 404.

Comment: Did you use exactly the pom.xml as linked? What name did you use?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I only retain the last part <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>

Comment: I had similar trouble last week and it was due to the pom.  Try using their sample.

Comment: I tried copying pom completely but still have an error.

Comment: try changing your `name` to `SpringMVC5` - Also what webserver are you deploying to ?  Any errors whilsts starting it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-

You should list all your packages  including configuration classes in @ComponentScan annotation instead main.java :
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config","controller"})`

Or

Move all your packages inside a parent package (example : com.project) like 
com.project.config, com.project.controller, com.project.model and use it:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project"})`

2- Check the web dependency assembly of your project, it should be like this:
[image]

If is your config not like this, you should add it by clicking on Add button and selecting java Build Path Entries.

[image]

And select Maven Dependencies in the next window.

Comment: thank you. this work for me. so my problem is the jar files is not in the proper place? right?

Comment: If you are running the project as dynamic web project on a server within eclipse, you should config Deployment Assembly if is not configured,This will instruct WTP to send the maven dependencies to the server dir. on the other hand if you build with maven, maven will move the dependencies jars in the lib folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible issues is that you package naming is wrong.
Folder structure for maven projects looks like that:

```
src
  |_ main
  |     |_ java
  |     |     |_ your.actual.package
  |     |_ resources
  |     |_ webapp
  |_ test
        |_ java
              |_ your.actual.package
```

So your actual package starts right after `java` folder. That means that you actually have:

- `config` package instead of `main.java.config` for `AppConfig` class
- `controller` package instead of `main.java.controller` for `JavaController`
- `model` package instead of `main.java.model` for `HelloWorld`

Also you need to change your `@ComponentScan`. Leave it empty to scan root package. Or try to use `basePackageClasses` if that doesn't work.

Afterwards you need to check you `war` file. Unpack it and check that `WEB-INF` folder contains `.class` files for all created classes and `views` has your `helloworld.jsp` file.

I hope this will help.

Comment: src/main/java then I add package com.test.config, leave the scan empty and nothing change. Do you think there is a problem during my setup?

Comment: You can try to change `@ComponentScan` to point to your `com.test` package. But it generally hard to tell what else could be wrong. Did you take a look inside `war` file? Is everything there (classes, jsps)? Is folder structure inside war good? What is in tomcat logs? There should something about your `InternalResourceViewResolver ` there which could help you to find the issue.

Comment: the war file is good everything is there, only an error in jsp file, but the structure is all good. inside the tomcat log only this line looks bad
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is exactly the problem, but here is a complete project for you.
You can get help from here:

https://github.com/imrangthub/BlogSolutionUsingSpringHibernateWithClassLevelConfig

Comment: thank you for your help, but I want to learn what I did wrong.